# How to: Bind Each Table of a DataSet to a Page on a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, dataset

I've searched and searched, and I think this should be rather straight forward, but I can't figure it out. I have a DataSet (myDataSet) to which I have added several tables (myDataTable). I also have a GridView. I want to set the GridView up so that each page on the GridView is bound to each each table of the DataSet (i.e. page 1 of GridView = DataSet.Table[0], etc.). The tables all have the same columns, but differing number of rows.

With PageSize = number of rows in the table, the buttons disappear completely even though I have explicitly set PageButtonCount to 3 (there are 3 tables in this dataset). I suppose there's some sort of automagical paging feature that's determining that no more pages are needed but I can't sort out how to make it work.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Users theUsers = new Users();
    static DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    protected bool runReport()
    {
        ltError.Visible = false;
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AsteriskConn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                //sql query
                string sql = "SELECT calldate, src, dst, duration FROM cdr WHERE (src LIKE @ext AND dst > 9999)" +
                               "OR (dst LIKE @ext AND src > 9999) AND dst NOT LIKE '*%'";

                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                dbConn.Open();
                myDataSet.Tables.Clear();
                int j = ddlUsers.SelectedIndex;
                //loop through each user in the list and query the database for its cdr records with the sql query string
                foreach (int i in theUsers.groups[j].extensions)
                {
                    myDataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, dbConn);
                    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ext", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = i;
                    adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
                    myDataTable.TableName = i.ToString();
                    myDataSet.Tables.Add(myDataTable);
                }
                gvReport.DataSource = myDataSet;
                gvReport.AllowPaging = true;
                gvReport.PageSize = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                gvReport.PagerSettings.PageButtonCount = myDataSet.Tables.Count;
                gvReport.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.NumericFirstLast;
                gvReport.PagerSettings.Position = PagerPosition.Top;
                gvReport.PagerSettings.Visible = true;
                gvReport.DataBind();
                dbConn.Close();    
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void gvReport_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvReport.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvReport.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[e.NewPageIndex];
    gvReport.DataBind();
}
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">        
    <asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="gvReport_PageIndexChanging"
            onrowdatabound="gvReport_RowDataBound" Visible="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="true">
            <PagerSettings Position="Top" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltError" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Literal>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I think if you are binding the DataTable each time then `Paging` is not a good option for you. set `paging=false` and add links and the end of grid depending upon number of tables with same index and use the `link.click` event to bind the data.

Answer (score 0):

i think, you better add the page index buttons/link buttons, dynamically (or use repeater to show the page index buttons)